# How to set the percentage of width when the position is fixed is based on the width of the parent

Tags: css

Please check this example.

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
.father {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <footer>
    12312312313123123123
  </footer>
</div>
```

I want this footer's width percentage based on the `.father`.When I set `position: fixed;`, I know that the percentage of width is base on the viewport.I wander if there is a way to solve this.Thx.

Comment: the width of the parent is known, so you can use it

Comment: Do you want to `footer` to be fixed or it should cover full screen, does not matter it is fixed or not?

Comment: @Aman I just want the footer stick at the bottom of the full screen while its width based on the father element at the same time

Comment: why dont you make `father` fixed with 200px width?

Comment: @Aman I think it's a hack way

Comment: I don't think so, as you are setting child fixed. Fixed element no longer belongs to parent element, instead they respond with window screen. Its better we fixed the parent.